# In Trace32, is there a way to use relative paths that are relative to a .men file?

Tags: trace32

It seems that in Trace32, ~~~~ doesn't work as expected in .men files. Is there a way to get a relative path relative to the .men file?

Answer (score 0):

You would only be able to use ~~ to get the root T32 folder.

The menu file itself can be called with `MENU.ReProgram "~~~~/filename.men"` inside of a PRACTICE (.cmm) script—and some included demos do exactly that—but the “current directory” macro, ~~~~, is not available to a .men file.

As a very hacky workaround, you *could* generate a menu file using an external script and a menu template and then use `MENU.ReProgram`.